# Spring boot: how to config the embedded Jetty server with ServletContextHandler instead of WebAppContext

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Session management is not needed in our use case, but according to this [github](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/5124) issue, session feature is a mandate. How can I config spring to make it use ServletContextHandler instead of WebAppContext

Comment: I believe spring-boot uses `ServletContextHandler` already (not `WebAppContext`) - and runs it with jetty internal security and session handling disabled - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/jetty/JettyReactiveWebServerFactory.java#L178

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.7.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/web/embedded/jetty/JettyServletWebServerFactory.java I think this is actually used for start up.